# SED extract of a last and rest of the word

Tags: sed, extract

```
log=/u00/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.4/network/admin/listener.log
```

i want to extract like this

```
listener.log
/u00/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.4/network/admin/
```

Some one helped me with extracting listener.log. But am struck with the other one.

```
#echo $log | sed 's!.*/!!'
listener.log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s/log=\(.*\/\)\([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*\)/\2 \1/
```

First, select the parts, then print them out as you wish.

How this works:

- select greedy everything
- backtrack until you have a slash to conclude it with; put that part in first match
- select whatever comes after it, put it in second match
- Then, print second match first, and then the first match.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
log=/u00/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.4/network/admin/listener.log
echo "$(dirname "$log")"   # ==> /u00/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.4/network/admin
echo "$(basename "$log")"  # ==> listener.log
```

Also

```sh
echo "${log%/*}"   # ==> /u00/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.4/network/admin
echo "${log##*/}"  # ==> listener.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#echo $log | sed 's|[^/]*$||'
```

("Delete a string of non-slash characters followed by the end of the line.")